# Given values v1, v2, ..., which get updated one by one, maintain the maximum over subsets (v_i1, v_i2, ...)

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

To set some notation, we have an array of size `N` consisting of non-negative floats `V = [v1, v2, ..., vN]`, as well as `M` subsets `S1, S2, ..., SM` of `{1, 2, ..., N}` (the subsets will overlap).  We are interested in the quantities `w_j = max(v_i for i in Sj)`.  The problem is to devise a data structure which can maintain `w_j` as efficiently as possible, while the values in the array `V` get updated one by one.  We should assume that `M >> N`.

One idea is to construct the "inverse" of the subsets `S`, namely subsets `T1, T2, ..., TN` of `{1, 2, ..., M}` such that `i in Sj` if and only if `j in Ti`.  Then, if `vi` is updated, scan every `j in Ti` and calculate `w_j` from scratch.  This takes `O(TN)` time, where `T` is the maximum size of any `Ti` subset.

I believe I see a way to maintain these in `O(T log N)` time, but the algorithm involves a rather convoluted structure of copies of binary search trees and lookup tables.  Is there a simpler data structure to use or a simple known solution to this problem?  does this problem have a name?

As well, since we have `M >> N`, it would be ideal to reduce the complexity from `O(M)`, but is this even possible?

Edit: The goal is to construct some data structure which allows efficiently maintaining the maximums when the V array is updated.  You cannot construct this data structure in less than O(M) time, but it may be possible to update it in less then that whenever a single entry of the V array changes.

Comment: You have M sets, and you must read them at least on time to find maximum. So the lower bound of any algorithm is M and we can't do better than O(M).

Answer (score 0):

According to my comment, We have M sets that maybe have overlap. On the other hand, each set contains at least one number. So we need to read at least one time M sets with size at least 1. as a result our lower bound for this problem is Ω(M).

Comment: I'm not trying to calculate these maxima in less then O(M) time, but to maintain them as V is updated.  If there is a data structure that allows maintaining them in O(log M) time per update, but requires even O(2^M) time to construct, that would be a success.